# Ubuntu 15.10 can ping IP and host name from terminal but not connect in browser

Tags: networking, 15.10, dns, browser

I just started a new job and have Ubuntu 15.10 on my work computer. We rely a lot on a local network/share drives and while I can ping both the IP and host name (i.e. 'suite' is what it's called here) without issue, no matter what I do I can't get any browsers to connect. Chrome gives a 'name not resolved' error, and Firefox just says page cannot be displayed. I tried using both wireless and wired connections, and messed with the proxy settings in both browsers a bit. I took it to our IT guy who messed around with it a bit and then handed it back to me saying he just didn't know, but I'm only the second employee here who wants to use Ubuntu instead of windows/osx.

Can anyone help? I don't want to be stuck using windows because of some network issue!

Comment: What's your real issue here?  Your computer can "ping" things, which is great, but if you're getting a "Name Not Resolved" then either the web browser doesn't work with `/etc/hosts` (if `/etc/hosts` has a hardcoded hostname -> IP item in there), or your DNS servers, assigned domain, and search domains are ***NOT*** configured right (not using the internal DNS resolver, not setting the internal domain correctly to the domain in use by your workplace, etc.).  We basically need a lot more information than is provided here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not particularly network-literate. When I ping the host name or IP, I get the following...

    $ ping suite
    PING prod-vnt01.maponics.local (10.1.10.229) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 10.1.10.229: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.38 ms
    64 bytes from 10.1.10.229: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.637 ms

nslookup also finds these servers, address, etc.

However, if I try to type in the url or the IP address into a browser, any browser I've installed, I get an error message. Both of these work on my windows computer, and for everyone else.

Comment: What's the exact error message, "Name Not Resolved", etc.?  What does `nslookup prod-vnt01.maponics.local` return?

Comment: Sorry for the awful formatting in the previous post.  
  
`~$ nslookup prod-vnt01.maponics.local  
Server:  127.0.1.1  
Address: 127.0.1.1#53  
  
Name: prod-vnt01.maponics.local  
Address: 10.1.10.229`

Comment: And, in Chrome there's a 'name not resolved', in Firefox is just says the page cannot be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by manually adding the IP address and hostname in question to my /etc/hosts file:

`sudo gedit /etc/hosts/`

and then below the entries that were already there, I added the IP/hostname that I found using nslookup.